# filling empty spaces in a vector of longs with zeroes

Tags: java, arrays, vector

i have a vector capacity of 10 and size of 5. I'm trying to fill the rest of the spaces with zeros by doing it in the method `padVectorWithZeores()` right now the vector looks like this:

```
2 -1 4 5 3
```

what I'm trying to get is

```
2 -1 4 5 3 0 0 0 0 0
```

I'm trying to do it in a for loop but i keep getting

```
2 -1 4 5 3 0
```

and its not filling the rest spaces with zeroes

```
import java.util.*;

public class VectOfLongs {

   private long[] theNumbers;    
   private int size, capacity; 

   public void padVectorWithZeroes() {

       for(int i=size; i<capacity; i++){
           theNumbers[capacity]=0;
       }

       size++;
   }

   public static void yourMainMethod() {    
       VectOfLongs v = new VectOfLongs();
       v.insert(2); v.insert(-1);  v.insert(-2);
       v.insert(4); v.insert(5); v.insert(3);
       System.out.println(v);
       System.out.println(v.howManyOddAndPositive());   

       v.padVectorWithZeroes();
       System.out.println(v);
    }

    public VectOfLongs() {
       size = 0;
       capacity = 5;
       theNumbers = new long[capacity];
    }

    public void insert(long l) {
       if (size==capacity) {
          long[] tmp = new long[capacity+5];
          capacity += 5;
          for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
             tmp[i] = theNumbers[i];
          theNumbers = tmp;
      }
      theNumbers[size++] = l;
   }
```

Comment: Is `yourMainMethod` your main method?  Why is it not defined that way?  Where is `howManyOffAndPositive()` defined?  These are silly questions and likely have nothing to do with your issue, but if people have to spend a lot of time trying to debug your code to even get it to compile, you should have spent more time formulating your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void padVectorWithZeroes() {

   for(int i=size; i<capacity; i++){
       theNumbers[capacity]=0;
   }

   size++; /// What is this?
}
```

you want to set `size = capacity` right?

Also note that the [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) says that when you create a new `long`, it will be filled with zero automatically (unlike C). So you do not need the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

With some assumptions, it's likely that this block:

```
for(int i=size; i<capacity; i++){
   theNumbers[capacity]=0;
}
```

Should be

```
for(int i=size; i<capacity; i++){
   theNumbers[i]=0;   // Note the array index changed
}
```

There are other deeper issues, but at least this compiles and runs without an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**Edit:** Working example here: http://ideone.com/dU09QD